# How to make a button in Flutter have the same shape as its icon?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

I am trying to create a backspace button (using an `ElevatedButton()`). I don't want the button to be circular, but instead have the same shape as the icon. Also, when tapping the button, I want the splash effect to be the same size and shape as the button.

I've attached a reference image below of the shape I'm trying to replicate.

Extra challenge: I'm also trying to set the fill color of the button to be black and the color of the button to be grey (like the example).

[image: Backspace button on iOS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`IconButton()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html) widget instead of `ElevtaedButton()` as well as defining the `splashRadius` to change the size of the splash effect:

```dart
IconButton(
            splashRadius: 1, // Set the Size of the splash area
            color: Colors.grey,
            icon: Icon(Icons.backspace),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
```

Result:

[image]

Or, if you want to use `ElevatedButton()`, use the [`.icon`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton/ElevatedButton.icon.html) constructor:

```dart
 ElevatedButton.icon(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.grey.shade300),
            label: Text('Hello World'),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.backspace,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out!

Do you know how I could change the fill of the "X" in the backspace `IconButton()`?

Comment: @RobertHinckley I'm not sure how to change fill color since if we were to change the fill color it also changes the `IconButton()`'s color

Answer (score 0):

There are many default icons in class `Icons` are not good-looking for your app. You can use some design platform, such as Figma, then download it as `svg`. Then the code could be:

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {},
  child: SvgPicture.asset(path_to_svg_icon)
)
```

This way, you can edit color, shape, style... for your icon. Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).